# Connecting Remote Service from different application in Android

Tags: android, service, aidl

I am trying to create sample application in android which could access the remote service already created in android.

Below are the code of my service, it's AIDL and sample application. Please note that I am trying to run it in android emulator.

My AIDL file

```
// IMyAidlInterface.aidl
package com.example.mmjoshi.binderservice;

// Declare any non-default types here with import statements

interface IMyAidlInterface {
    /**
     * Demonstrates some basic types that you can use as parameters
     * and return values in AIDL.
     */
    int findFactorialService(int x);

}
```

My Service file

```
package com.example.mmjoshi.binderservice;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Binder;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.os.RemoteException;

/**
 * Created by mmjoshi on 8/12/2015.
 */
public class MyService extends Service {
    private final IBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder();
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent)
    {
        //return mBinder;
        return new IMyAidlInterface.Stub(){
            public int findFactorialService(int x) throws RemoteException
            {
                int fact =1;
                for(int i=1;i<=x;i++)
                {
                    fact = fact*i;
                }
                return  fact;
                //return 5;
            }
        };
    }



    public class LocalBinder extends Binder
    {
        public MyService getService()
        {
            return MyService.this;
        }
    }

    /*public int findFactorial(int x)
    {
        int fact =1;
        for(int i=1;i<=x;i++)
        {
            fact = fact*i;
        }
        return  fact;
        //return 5;
    }*/
}
```

Service Manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.mmjoshi.binderservice" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <service android:name=".MyService" android:process=":remote"
            android:enabled="true" android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.example.mmjoshi.binderservice.MyService.IMyAidlInterface"></action>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Another application which access this service

```
package secondndapp.service_client;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.ServiceConnection;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.os.RemoteException;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.mmjoshi.binderservice.IMyAidlInterface;


public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

    EditText etValue1, etValue2;
    Button bAdd;
    ServiceConnection AddServiceConnection;
    protected IMyAidlInterface iMyAidlInterface;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        etValue1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtinput);
        bAdd = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnCalc);
        bAdd.setOnClickListener(this);
        initConnection();
    }

    void initConnection() {
        AddServiceConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
            @Override
            public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {

                iMyAidlInterface = IMyAidlInterface.Stub.asInterface((IBinder) service);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Service Connected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
                Log.d("IRemote", "Binding is done - Service connected");
            }

            @Override
            public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
                iMyAidlInterface = null;
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Service Disconnected",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.d("IRemote", "Binding - Service disconnected");


            }
        };
        if (iMyAidlInterface == null) {
            Intent it = new Intent("com.example.mmjoshi.binderservice.MyService");
            it.setPackage("com.example.mmjoshi");
            it.setAction("com.example.mmjoshi.binderservice.MyService.IMyAidlInterface");
            it.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.example.mmjoshi", "com.example.mmjoshi.binderservice.MyService"));
            // binding to remote service
            startService(it);
            Log.d("Service-MJ","Service is going to start");
            bindService(it, AddServiceConnection, Service.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
            Log.d("Service-MJ", "Service is started");
        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        int num = Integer.parseInt(etValue1.getText().toString());
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "num is " + num,
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        int result = 0;
        try {
            result = iMyAidlInterface.findFactorialService(num);
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Result" + result,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }


}
```

Now, first I run the Binder Service in emulator and then I run this application in emulator.

But I am getting this error: "*java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'int com.example.mmjoshi.binderservice.IMyAidlInterface.findFactorialService(int)' on a null object reference*"

Please help me, I am stuck with this since last 2 days.

Thanks in Advance.

Maulik

Comment: do you see "Binding is done - Service Connected" in your logcat?

Comment: No, I don't see it in logcat

Comment: "Service is going to start", "Service is started" ?

Comment: I can see that, but in between of them, I can see this line:

08-14 10:36:46.092     506-1939/system_process W/ActivityManager﹕ Unable to start service Intent { act=com.example.mmjoshi.binderservice.MyService.IMyAidlInterface pkg=com.example.mmjoshi cmp=com.example.mmjoshi/.binderservice.MyService } U=0: not found

Comment: so your intent is wrong: see answer below

Comment: I am actually, accessing the service from the another app and not from the same app. That's the reason I have intent-filter.

Also, as per your suggestion:

Intent it = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
bindService(it, AddServiceConnection, Service.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);

I will not get the "MyService.class" because I am accessing the service in different application.

Comment: i think you should read Intent documentation, all you do is redundant: first you create an Intent with the action (new Intent(String)), then you set package, then action again, then component, please read Intent documentation

Comment: It works.. I changed my Intent to
`Intent it = new Intent();`
`it.setAction("com.example.mmjoshi.binderservice.MyService.IMyAidlInterface");`
`it.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.example.mmjoshi.binderservice", "com.example.mmjoshi.binderservice.MyService"));`
`Log.d("Service-MJ","Service is going to start");`
`bindService(it, AddServiceConnection, Service.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);`
`Log.d("Service-MJ", "Service is started");`

Thank you very much @CommonsWare & @pskink for your quick response and help..